# How to resolve Compile time Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<ExceptionLog__c>

Tags: error-messages, dmlexception

I've a generic class which detects the type of exception and redirects to another utility class for displaying specific message for exceptions. Now for a certain scenario I want to display a different message rather than the generic one for DML exception. So, i've put a condition on the class name from the exception log , but I'm getting this error. any idea as to how i can solve this?

```
public static void ExceptionHandling(Exception e,List<ExceptionLog__c> eLog)
{

if(e.getTypeName()=='System.DMLException') {

    for(List<ExceptionLog__c> eL : eLog){
        if(eL.ClassName__c = 'myclassName')
            ExceptionUtility.reWriteDisplayDmlExceptionMessage2UI(LABEL.Errormessage,e, eLog);  
        else   
            ExceptionUtility.reWriteDisplayDmlExceptionMessage2UI(LABEL.ErrorDmlException,e, eLog); 
          }                                     
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple typo; you want to get each *individual* element from the list, so the type of the iterator element should be simply `ExceptionLog__c`, not a List:

```
for(ExceptionLog__c eL: eLog) {
```

As a side note, you're also confusing assignment (`=`) with equality (`==`), so the following line is an error:

```
if(eL.ClassName__c = 'myclassName')
```

This will actually try to assign the value of 'myclassName' to `eL.ClassName__c`, and since the result type is not a Boolean value, you'll get another compiler error here. Change it to `==` so you get a Boolean value. Watch out for this syntax, because it can cause errors (e.g. if you try to assign a Boolean value to a checkbox field).

There are times when you want to use a `List<SObject>` type iterator type, and that's when you are using a query as the list to iterate over; this has the effect of giving you 200 records at once for processing, which can save memory:

```
for(Account[] records: [SELECT Name FROM Account]) {
    // We get 200 records at a time for processing.
```

This syntax doesn't skirt any limits, such as the 50,000 row limit, but internally uses a QueryLocator to grab 200 records at a time efficiently, reducing the memory cost of a large query for inline processing. The list to iterate over must be some sort of query result, not an existing list of records either constructed in memory or from a prior query.

Comment: Got it, made the changes and it's working.